# Reading a file and adding a specific match to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, regex

Id like to read a file for a specific match in the following style "word = word", specifically Im looking to find files with usernames and passwords in them. These files would be scripts created by admins using bad practices with clear credentials being used in logonscripts etc.

The code I have created so far does the job but its very messy and prints an entire line if the match is found (I cant help but think there is a more elegant way to do this). This creates ugly output, id like to print only the match in the line. I cant seem to find a way to do that. If I can create the correct regex for a match of something like the below match, is it possible to only print the match found in the line rather than the entire line?

(I am going to try describe the type of match im looking for)

**Key**

- * = wildcard
- - = space
- ^ = anycharacter until a space

**Match**

*(U|u)ser^-=-^

```
dirt = "/dir/path/"
def get_files():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirt):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(('.bat', '.vbs', '.ps', '.txt')):
                readfile = open(os.path.join(root, filename), "r")
                for line in readfile:
                    if re.match("(.*)(U|u)ser(.*)", line) and re.match("(.*)(=)(.*)", line) or re.match("(.*)(P|p)ass(.*)", line) and re.match("(.*)(=)(.*)", line):
                        print line
```

**TEST SCRIPT**

```
strComputer = "atl-ws-01"
strNamespace = “root\cimv2”
strUser = "Administrator"
strPassword = "4rTGh2#1"
user = AnotherUser #Test
pass = AnotherPass #test

Set objWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objWMIService = objwbemLocator.ConnectServer _
(strComputer, strNamespace, strUser, strPassword)
objWMIService.Security_.authenticationLevel = WbemAuthenticationLevelPktPrivacy

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * From Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objItem in ColItems
Wscript.Echo strComputer & ": " & objItem.Caption
Next
```

**Latest Code after taking on bored the responses**

This is the latest code I am using. It seems to be doing the job as expected, apart from the output isnt managed as well as Id like. Id like to add the items into a dictionary. Key being the file name. And two vaules, the username and password. Although this will be added as a separate question.

Thanks all for the help

```
dirt = "~/Desktop/tmp"

def get_files():
    regs = ["(.*)((U|u)ser(.*))(\s=\s\W\w+\W)", "(.*)((U|u)ser(.*))(\s=\s\w+)", "(.*)((P|p)ass(.*))\s=\s(\W(.*)\W)", "(.*)((P|p)ass(.*))(\s=\s\W\w+\W)"]
    combined = "(" + ")|(".join(regs) + ")"
    results = dict()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirt):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(('.bat', '.vbs', '.ps', '.txt')):
            readfile = open(os.path.join(root, filename), "r")
        for line in readfile:
            m = re.match(combined, line)
            if m:
                print os.path.join(root, filename)
                print m.group(0)
```

**Latest Code output**

```
~/Desktop/tmp/Domain.local/Policies/{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}/USER/Scripts/Logon/logonscript1.vbs
strUser = "guytom"
~/Desktop/tmp/DLsec.local/Policies/{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}/USER/Scripts        /Logon/logonscript1.vbs
strPassword = "P@ssw0rd1"

~/Desktop/tmp/DLsec.local/Policies/{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}/USER/Scripts/Logon/logonscript2.bat
strUsername = "guytom2"
~/Desktop/tmp/DLsec.local/Policies/{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}/USER/Scripts/Logon/logonscript2.bat
strPass = "SECRETPASSWORD"
```

Comment: what is the difference between 'words' and 'anycharacter until a space'?

Comment: hahaha ermmmm the way it is spelt? Ill remove words :P thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You may just want to split the line on '=' and strip off the spaces. op=line.partition("="); (user,pwd)=(x.strip() for x in (op[0],op[2]))

Comment: sorry, but most of what you just said doesnt mean a great deal to me. Could you create an answer with a simple example?

Comment: Can you give test cases and the desired output as well? It would help understanding your problem and outline it better.

Comment: I shall add a test file into my original question

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

group([group1, ...])
    Returns one or more subgroups of the match. If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match is returned). If a groupN argument is zero, the corresponding return value is the entire matching string;

```
match.group(0)
```

Comment: Ok no idea what you just said ^_^ but I will do some research around match groups and how to use them. If they work like I think they do (after my good look at the docs) I can create multiple groups for patterns like `(.*)(U|u)ser(\w+)\s(\=\s)(\w+)` and return the "found" matches. (hopes ive understood that correctly at first glace)

Comment: When you call `re.match` you get back an object. you can call `group(0)` on that object, and it will give you all the text it matched.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can have many object=value you need to use regular expressions. Here is some sample code for you.

```
line1 = " someuser =  bob "
line2 = " bob'spasswd=  secretpassword"
#re.I will do case insensitive search
userMatchObj=re.search('.*user.*=\\s*([\\S]*).*', line1, re.I)
pwdMatchObj=re.search(r'.*pass.*=\s*(.*)', line2, re.I)

if userMatchObj: print "user="+userMatchObj.group(1)
if pwdMatchObj: print "password="+pwdMatchObj.group(1)
```

output:

```
user=bob
password=secretpassword
```

References: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html , http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Comment: I dont think this would work well as there are a lot of `object=value` items in a scipt not just the `username=administrator` and `password=secretpassword`

Comment: Will you have both username and password on the same line?

Comment: maybe, its an unknown but its possible. But there will be other items with the same sort of pattern. thisthing = this (Your code looks like it will split all things with `=` in it and print the item and its value. Or am I not interpreting it correctly?

Comment: I updated it to use regular expressions since you will have many object=value pairs and need to look for user and pass keywords in an insensitive manner.

Comment: Thanks however that regex pretty much returns all text in the docs ^_^ [heres example script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/12/13/how-can-i-run-a-script-under-alternate-credentials.aspx)

Comment: You are right. I fixed it. Since I had user and pass surrounded by [] it was matching each character. Also this will keep the quotes around since you didn't specify to strip them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help. Below is my working code (needs further work on the output but the matching is working well)

```
dirt = "~/Desktop/tmp"

def get_files():
    regs = ["(.*)((U|u)ser(.*))(\s=\s\W\w+\W)", "(.*)((U|u)ser(.*))(\s=\s\w+)", "(.*)((P|p)ass(.*))\s=\s(\W(.*)\W)", "(.*)((P|p)ass(.*))(\s=\s\W\w+\W)"]
    combined = "(" + ")|(".join(regs) + ")"
    results = dict()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirt):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(('.bat', '.vbs', '.ps', '.txt')):
                readfile = open(os.path.join(root, filename), "r")
                for line in readfile:
                    m = re.match(combined, line)
                    if m:
                        print os.path.join(root, filename)
                        print m.group(0)
```

**Latest Code output**

```
~/Desktop/tmp/Domain.local/Policies/{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}/USER/Scripts/Logon/logonscript1.vbs
strUser = "guytom"
~/Desktop/tmp/DLsec.local/Policies/{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}/USER/Scripts/Logon/logonscript1.vbs
strPassword = "P@ssw0rd1"

~/Desktop/tmp/DLsec.local/Policies/{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}/USER/Scripts/Logon/logonscript2.bat
strUsername = "guytom2"
~/Desktop/tmp/DLsec.local/Policies/{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}/USER/Scripts/Logon/logonscript2.bat
strPass = "SECRETPASSWORD"
```